# Physics object with force field render oddly shaped and jagged

Tags: animation, physics, force-fields

This question still puzzles me: When f-12-rendering (both Cycles and Eevee) frames with a cloth animation the banner-object behind the airplane appears oddly shaped and utterly jagged.

[image: viewport render]
[image: frame render]
[image: Modifier settings]

[Please inspect the blend-file -->](https://drive.google.com/open?id=192o6U6VgBh-tqb8PkWgF7Y1BgL5K3wpz)

EDIT: Modifier settings added

In the viewport its seems ok and I can’t figure out where to look for a better result. What may I have done wrong? I would be very glad for your opinion.

Kind regards, Mikael

Comment: I'm not in the habit of downloading files just to understand the question... but are the preview and render settings for  subsurf modifier the same (or for any other modifier for that matter?)

Comment: Understand :-)
Added image with render settings in post

Comment: change the order of the modifiers... cloth first and then subsurf

Comment: Also, don't be stingy with information as part of the question. Show the whole interface. Help others help you, don't make it detective work...

Comment: Very good, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the modifiers was the cause of jagged shape!

Changed the subdivision modifier after the cloth simulation.

[image]